# debuggable false in android studio 0.4.5

Tags: android, debugging

```
<application
        android:debuggable="false"
```

get a error saying "Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one"

I deleted what is up in AndroidManifest and I add this in the build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebugBuild true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild true
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile files('build/libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
}
```

but still does not work when i upload to play store

thanks

Comment: i resolved with
 buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        foo{
            debuggable false
        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used and it worked perfectly

```
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable false
    }
    release {
        runProguard false
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```